# multiple results of one variable when applying tm method "stemCompletion"

Tags: r, rstudio, tm, stemming

I have a corpus containing journal data of 15 observations of 3 variables (ID, title, abstract). Using R Studio I read in the data from a .csv file (one line per observation).
When performing some text mining operations I got some trouble when using the method stemCompletion. 
After applying stemCompletion I observed that the results are provided for each stemmed line of the .csv three times. All the other tm methods (e.g. stemDocument) produce only a single result. I'm wondering why this happens and how I could fix the problem

I used the code below:

```
data.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data))  
data.corpuscopy <- data.corpus
data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, stemDocument)
data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, stemCompletion, dictionary=data.corpuscopy)
```

The single results after applying stemDocument is e.g.

```
"> data.corpus[[1]]

physic environ   sourc  innov investig  attribut  innov space
          investig  physic space intersect  innov  innov     relev attribut  physic space   innov        reflect  chang natur  innov  technolog advanc  servic  mean chang  argu   develop  innov space similar embodi  divers set  valu   collabor open  sustain use  literatur review interview  benchmark    examin  relationship  physic environ  innov         literatur review   interview underlin innov   communic  human centr process   result five attribut  innov space  present collabor enabl modifi smart attract   reflect       provid perspect   challeng    support innov creation  develop physic space   add   conceptu develop  innov space  outlin physic space   innov servic"
```

And after using stemCompletion the reults appear three times:

```
"$`1`
physical environment source innovation investigation attributes innovation space investigation physical space intersect innovation innovation relevant attributes physical space innovation reflect changes nature innovation technological advancements service meanwhile changes argues develop innovation space similarity embodies diversified set valuable collaboration open sustainability used literature review interviews benchmarking examine relationships physical environment innovation literature review interviews underline innovation communicative human centred processes result five attributes innovation space present collaboration enablers modifiability smartness attractiveness reflect provide perspectives challenge support innovation creation develop physical space addition conceptual develop innovation space outlines physical space innovation service
physical environment source innovation investigation attributes innovation space investigation physical space intersect innovation innovation relevant attributes physical space innovation reflect changes nature innovation technological advancements service meanwhile changes argues develop innovation space similarity embodies diversified set valuable collaboration open sustainability used literature review interviews benchmarking examine relationships physical environment innovation literature review interviews underline innovation communicative human centred processes result five attributes innovation space present collaboration enablers modifiability smartness attractiveness reflect provide perspectives challenge support innovation creation develop physical space addition conceptual develop innovation space outlines physical space innovation service
physical environment source innovation investigation attributes innovation space investigation physical space intersect innovation innovation relevant attributes physical space innovation reflect changes nature innovation technological advancements service meanwhile changes argues develop innovation space similarity embodies diversified set valuable collaboration open sustainability used literature review interviews benchmarking examine relationships physical environment innovation literature review interviews underline innovation communicative human centred processes result five attributes innovation space present collaboration enablers modifiability smartness attractiveness reflect provide perspectives challenge support innovation creation develop physical space addition conceptual develop innovation space outlines physical space innovation service"
```

Below is a sample as a reproducable example:

A .csv file containing three observations of three variables:

```
ID;Text A;Text B
1;Below is the first title;Innovation and Knowledge Management
2;And now the second Title;Organizational Performance and Learning are very important
3;The third title;Knowledge plays an important rule in organizations
```

And below is the stemming method that I've used

```
data = read.csv2("Test.csv")
data[,2]=as.character(data[,2])
data[,3]=as.character(data[,3])

corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data)) 
corpuscopy <- corpus
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus[[1]]

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemCompletion, dictionary=corpuscopy)
inspect(corpus[1:3])
```

It seems to me like it depends on the number of variables used in the .csv but I have no idea why.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be something odd about the `stemCompletion` function. It's not obvious how to use `stemCompletion` in the `tm` version 0.6. There is a nice workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391686/1036500) that I've used for this answer.

First, make the CSV file that you have:

```
dat <- read.csv2( text = 
                  "ID;Text A;Text B
1;Below is the first title;Innovation and Knowledge Management
2;And now the second Title;Organizational Performance and Learning are very important
3;The third title;Knowledge plays an important rule in organizations")

write.csv2(dat, "Test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Read it in, transform to a corpus, and stem the words:

```
data = read.csv2("Test.csv")
data[,2]=as.character(data[,2])
data[,3]=as.character(data[,3])

corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data)) 
corpuscopy <- corpus
library(SnowballC)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
```

Have a look to see that it's worked:

```
inspect(corpus)

<<VCorpus (documents: 3, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
1
Below is the first titl
Innovat and Knowledg Manag

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
2
And now the second Titl
Organiz Perform and Learn are veri import

[[3]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
3
The third titl
Knowledg play an import rule in organ
```

Here's the nice workaround to get `stemCompletion` working:

```
stemCompletion_mod <- function(x,dict=corpuscopy) {
  PlainTextDocument(stripWhitespace(paste(stemCompletion(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x)," ")),dictionary=dict, type="shortest"),sep="", collapse=" ")))
}
```

Inspect the output to see if the stems were completed ok:

```
lapply(corpus, stemCompletion_mod)

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
1 Below is the first title Innovation and Knowledge Management

[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
2 And now the second Title Organizational Performance and Learning are NA important

[[3]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
3 The third title Knowledge plays an important rule in organizations
```

Success!